# CListCtrl and std::list in MFC applications

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, clistctrl

I work on an application on MFC, I encountered a problem with the CListCtrl controller wish I use to create a list control !
So when I use that code for my function ViewALL (for test), everything works fine:

```
void CFactureView::ViewALL()
{
    int i = 0 ;

    m_FactureList.DeleteAllItems();

            m_FactureList.InsertItem(i,_T("TEST"));
            m_FactureList.SetItemText(i,1,_T("TEST"));
            m_FactureList.SetItemText(i,2,_T("TEST"));
            m_FactureList.SetItemText(i,3,_T("TEST"));
            m_FactureList.SetItemText(i,4,_T("TEST"));
            m_FactureList.SetItemText(i,5,_T("TEST"));
            m_FactureList.SetItemText(i,6,_T("TEST"));
            m_FactureList.SetItemText(i,7,_T("TEST"));
            m_FactureList.SetItemText(i,8,_T("TEST"));
            m_FactureList.SetItemText(i,9,_T("TEST"));
}
```

But with this, nothing happened :
`m_FactureList` is the name of my controller.

```
void CFactureView::ViewALL()
{
    m_FactureList.DeleteAllItems();
    int i = 0 ;
    CString annee, mois, imp, reg, bilan ;
    //Parcourir la liste des factures
        for(std::list<CInfoFacture>::iterator it=GetDocument()->m_listFacture.begin();
                                      it!=GetDocument()->m_listFacture.end(); it++)
        { 
            annee.Format(_T("%d"),it->m_Date.m_Annee);
            mois.Format(_T("%d"),it->m_Date.m_Mois);
            imp.Format(_T("%.*f"),2,it->m_MontantIMP);
            reg.Format(_T("%.*f"),2,it->m_MontantREG);
            bilan.Format(_T("%.*f"),2,it->m_Bilan);

            m_FactureList.InsertItem(i,it->pAdmin->m_MonCentre->m_nomCentre);
            m_FactureList.SetItemText(i,1,it->pAdmin->m_nomAdmin);
            m_FactureList.SetItemText(i,2,it->m_Police);
            m_FactureList.SetItemText(i,3,annee);
            m_FactureList.SetItemText(i,4,mois);
            m_FactureList.SetItemText(i,5,it->m_NumFacture);
            m_FactureList.SetItemText(i,6,imp);
            m_FactureList.SetItemText(i,7,reg);
            m_FactureList.SetItemText(i,8,it->m_Bons);
            m_FactureList.SetItemText(i,9,bilan);

            i++;
        }
}
```

`m_listFacture` is a list wish I use to store the information (`CInfoFacture` classes)
The list is declared in the `CFactureDoc` (`CDocument` Class) :

```
class CFactureDoc : public CDocument
{
protected: // création à partir de la sérialisation uniquement
    CFactureDoc();
    DECLARE_DYNCREATE(CFactureDoc)

// Attributs
public:
    std::list<CCentre> m_listCentre; // Listes des centres
    std::list<CAdministration> m_listAdmin; // Listes des administrations
    std::list<CInfoFacture> m_listFacture; // Listes des factures 
// Opérations
 // Extra code here !
 //
}
```

Comment: What does MFC stand for?

Comment: @Walter it's [Microsoft Foundation Classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/d06h2x6e(v=VS.100).aspx).

Comment: Would you be willing to make a reference to your list such that accessing it is easier: 
std::list<CInfoFacture>& mylist = GetDocument()->m_listFacture;
for(std::list<CInfoFacture>::iterator it=mylist.begin(); it!=mylist; it++)
{
   //...
}
Probably won't help

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion !
Still not working :P

Comment: Are you sure the m_listFacture collection actually contains elements? And aren't you missing a call to DeleteAllItems() before populating the ListControl?

Comment: Put a breakpoint somewhere inside your for loop. My crystal ball tells me the breakpoint won't be hit.

Comment: To Sébastien Côté :
It's already in the original code, I just missed it.

Comment: To Michael Walz :
Nothing new :P

Comment: What is this supposed to do? `imp.Format(_T("%.*f"),2,it->m_MontantIMP)` It should be `Format(L"%f",0.123)` or something like: `Format(L"%2.2f",0.123)`. It's same as `printf`... Also don't just increament `i`. Use `i=list.InsertItem(...)` to get the index where item was inserted.

Comment: To Barmak Shemirani :
I use it to convert a `double` to `CString` ,  and the `_T("")` is a macro for the Unicode application.
I try what you suggest, but nothing changed.

Comment: Then it's not a problem with list control. Comment out everything in the loop and debug with something like this: `TRACE("Test: %s, %.2f\n", it->pAdmin->m_MonCentre->m_nomCentre, it->m_MontantIMP);` it should print the values in output window.

Comment: FYI C++/CLI is a superset of C++ which you're not using in this question. I'm removing the tag.